# Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: unable to parse the server version: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value with api-platform

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, api-platform.com, helm3

I want to upgrade my api-platform project with helm.

To do this, i use the kubernetes documentation from api-platform ( https://api-platform.com/docs/deployment/kubernetes/)
My problem is when i want to do the upgrade command :

helm upgrade main ./helm/api-platform --namespace=default --create-namespace --wait 
--install 
--set "php.image.repository=gcr.io/test-api-platform/php" 
--set php.image.tag=latest 
--set "caddy.image.repository=gcr.io/test-api-platform/caddy" 
--set caddy.image.tag=latest 
--set "pwa.image.repository=gcr.io/test-api-platform/pwa" 
--set pwa.image.tag=latest 
--set php.appSecret='!ChangeMe!' 
--set postgresql.postgresqlPassword='!ChangeMe!' 
--set postgresql.persistence.enabled=true 
--set "corsAllowOrigin=^https?://[a-z]*.mywebsite.com$"

When i did it in local it works perfectly but when i use gitlab-ci to deploy by using the same command i have this error :

Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: unable to parse the server version: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

I blocked since almost a week and i don't know what to do to correct that.

If someone have an idea, i take it !

Thanks !

Comment: I appears that Kubernetes cluster is not properly configured in gitlab-ci. https://aliartiza75.medium.com/gitlab-integration-with-kubernetes-46c2473a4396

Comment: i did eveything in this tutorial but there is still the same error :(